# Expo apk not loading

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, mobile, expo

I built an expo app and in the development it works fine (I'm using `expo run:android` to run the app), but when I generated the apk and installed it's doesn't work. The app never load, just show the expo screen. Anyone know what's happening here?

[image]

My apk:
https://exp-shell-app-assets.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/android/%40anti-duhring/sleeper-app-28be24ca7f74428db0b59af74750d82b-signed.apk

app.json:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "sleeper-app",
    "slug": "sleeper-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.antiduhring.sleeperapp"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

logcat:

```
06-30 17:36:28.964 13688 14145 W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: shell-app-manifest.json       
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:875)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:852)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.universal.ScopedFileSystemModule.getBundledAssets(ScopedFileSystemModule.kt:2)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at versioned.host.exp.exponent.modules.universal.ScopedFileSystemModule.getConstants(ScopedFileSystemModule.kt:2)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at expo.modules.adapters.react.NativeModulesProxy.getConstants(NativeModulesProxy.java:9)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.getConstants(JavaModuleWrapper.java:14)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(Native Method)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)    
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)   
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:28.965 13688 14145 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
06-30 17:36:28.982 13688 14145 D i       : WARNING: getPackageName called on ScopedContext
06-30 17:36:29.157 13688 14145 E ReactNativeJS: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.RATING_HEART')
06-30 17:36:29.166 13688 14145 I ReactNativeJS: Running "main
06-30 17:36:29.169 13688 14145 E ReactNativeJS: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
06-30 17:36:29.169 13688 14145 E ReactNativeJS: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
06-30 17:36:29.169 13688 14145 E ReactNativeJS: * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$1100(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:29.171 13688 14146 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: Caused by: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 't.RATING_HEART'), stack:
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@723:1143
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@723:1407
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: h@2:1585
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@722:1821
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: h@2:1585
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@720:415
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: h@2:1585
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@6:69
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: h@2:1585
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: d@2:958
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err: global code@1105:3
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err:    at host.exp.exponent.ReactNativeStaticHelpers.handleReactNativeError(ReactNativeStaticHelpers.kt:5)
06-30 17:36:29.172 13688 14146 W System.err:    ... 10 more
06-30 17:36:29.176 13688 14146 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultNativeModuleCallExceptionHandler.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.devsupport.DisabledDevSupportManager.handleException(DisabledDevSupportManager.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.onNativeException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.access$1100(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$NativeExceptionHandler.handleException(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: Caused by: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: * Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: * A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., stack:
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: exports@12:289
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: runApplication@337:2081
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: value@58:3579
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: <unknown>@58:758
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: value@58:2582
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: value@58:730
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err: value@-1
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    at host.exp.exponent.ReactNativeStaticHelpers.handleReactNativeError(ReactNativeStaticHelpers.kt:5)
06-30 17:36:29.177 13688 14146 W System.err:    ... 10 more
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by DeviceInfo
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.modules.deviceinfo.DeviceInfoModule.invalidate(DeviceInfoModule.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:29.195 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by NativeAnimatedModule
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.animated.NativeAnimatedModule.invalidate(NativeAnimatedModule.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: Unhandled SoftException
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule: java.lang.RuntimeException: Catalyst Instance has already disappeared: requested by FrescoModule
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule.getReactApplicationContextIfActiveOrWarn(ReactContextBaseJavaModule.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.modules.fresco.FrescoModule.invalidate(FrescoModule.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.destroy(ModuleHolder.java:2)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.notifyJSInstanceDestroy(NativeModuleRegistry.java:4)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl$1.run(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:1)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:8)
06-30 17:36:29.197 13688 14146 E unknown:ReactContextBaseJavaModule:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: this doc gives some advice on how to debug this: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/splash-screen-hanging.md

Comment: @brentvatne I don't use the `SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()` in the app... But I edited my post with my logcat, there's some information but I can't tell what is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Something was wrong with a specific package that I used ([react-native-track-player](https://react-native-track-player.js.org/)), it only worked with the repositore `jcenter()` declared inside the build.gradle, but they updated the package and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like after conversation with you index.bundle is not created

do this in same order

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd..
```

after cd paste code below:

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
```

after that

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease (not apk if you want to deploy to google play store)
cd ..
react-native run-android --variant=release
```

Comment: It is weird because my app run completely fine when is in the prebuild, but when I create the apk it is simply doesn't work.

Comment: @anti-duhring did you created index.bundle?

Comment: Actually, not. I I followed this tutorial: https://docs.expo.dev/classic/building-standalone-apps/ This index.bundle file has to be created?

Comment: do this:
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd..
after cd paste code below:
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/
after that 
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease (not apk if you want to deploy to google play store)
cd ..
react-native run-android --variant=release

Comment: thank you, but I found out what was the problem: https://github.com/doublesymmetry/react-native-track-player/issues/1588